# How can I edit a non-string data value in a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

Consider a data set with a number of columns.

```
> data <- import.csv("data.csv")
> head(data[1])

> Output:

    Sex
1   M
2   M
3   F
4   M
5   I
6   I
```

(Isolating the first column of my data set.) I want to change the F to M in all cases.

So I try the following:

```
> for (i in 1:6) {
      if (data[i, 1] == F) {
          data[i, 1] = M) 
      }
  }
```

This leaves the data unchanged. So I tried to import the data like so:

```
> data <- import.csv("data.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

The loop method works now, but this is not OK because with the F, M, and I as strings I cannot perform the logistic regression that I need to.

Any suggestions on changing F to M but not introducing strings?

Comment: If you just want to change the `F` values in `M` values, you don't need a loop, you can just do it like this:  data[data$Sex == 'F', Sex] = "M"

Comment: `F` is the abbreviation for `FALSE` ! You want to use `"F"` (as Barbara wrote).

Comment: As explained, I can't have strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change all rows in `data` where Sex is equal to the string `'F'`:

`data[data$Sex == 'F',] <- 'M'`

You haven't told us what these variable types should be. Are they objects? Should they be of a certain type?

Comment: Any type that is possible to use in a logistic regression (i.e. not strings)

Comment: Can you use factors? If so, just convert the input before you feed it into the model. `data$Sex <- as.factor(data$Sex)`

Answer (score 0):

Try

> Df$column <- ifelse(df$var== "F","M",df$var)

Comment: Is 'column' supposed to be 'var'?

Comment: Both are same, column and variable. Column name = variable
Row =observation